# Select a consecutive range of data.frame columns using names of beginning and end columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to subset the columns of a `data.frame` using the interval of column names.

For instance, the `data.frame` `A`:

```
A
ID1 ID2 ID3
1   5  01901
2   5  01902
```

For example, I want create variable b with the columns of A:

```
b=A[,"ID2":"ID3"]
```

> Error in "ID1":"ID3" : NA/NaN argument In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In `[.data.frame`(A, , "ID1":"ID3") : NAs introduced by coercion 2:
>   In `[.data.frame`(A, , "ID1":"ID3") : NAs introduced by coercion

What I want how solution:

```
b
ID2 ID3
5  01901
5  01902
```

When I put the indexes of the columns, it works. But when I use the column name, as above, does not work.

Comment: `A[, c('ID2', 'ID3')]`

Comment: I think the difference here is in the column range bit. The @Sotos, which is also the linked duplicate, is a bit incorrect if the intent is to span from `"IDx":"IDy"`

Comment: I agree with @Coatless that this is not a duplicate, and I've edited the question to make that clearer.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `c()` function, then it works when using column names

```
> A <- data.frame(ID1=c(1,1),ID2=c(5,5),ID3=c(01901,01902))
> A
#   ID1 ID2  ID3
# 1   1   5 1901
# 2   1   5 1902

> b <- A[,c(2:3)]
> b
#   ID2  ID3
# 1   5 1901
# 2   5 1902

> b1 <- A[,c("ID2","ID3")]
> b1
#   ID2  ID3
# 1   5 1901
# 2   5 1902

> b2 <- A[,2:3]
> b2
#   ID2  ID3
# 1   5 1901
# 2   5 1902
```

Answer (score 9):

Two approaches in `base` R's `data.frame`:

- Named vector column subset
- Interval approach

## Named vector column subset

First, subset by known name:

```
b = A[, c('ID2', 'ID3')]
```

## Interval approach

Second, subset by an interval when it is known the columns are the same:

```
# Column Variables
colvars = names(A)

# Get the first ID
start_loc = match("ID1",colvars)

# Get the second ID
end_loc = match("ID3",colvars)

# Subset range
b = A[,start_loc:end_loc]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not restricted to data.frame, you can convert it to data.table and then your formula will work:

```
data.table::setDT(A)[, ID2:ID3, with=F]

   ID2  ID3
1:   5 1901
2:   5 1902
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use column names instead of numbers to select a column interval, right? 
Why not:

`> b <- A[,c((which(colnames(A)=="ID2")):(which(colnames(A)=="ID3")))]`
 
`> b`
`#    ID2 ID3`
`# 1   5 1901`
`# 2   5 1902`

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use `dplyr`:

```
# create data frame A
A <- data.frame (ID1 = c("1", "2"),
             ID2 = c("5", "5"),
             ID3 = c("01901", "01902")
             )

# print A
A

# get data frame B
B <- A %>% select(ID2:ID3)

# print B
B
```

Answer (score 0):

The base R `subset` function can do this

```
subset(A, ID2:ID3)
```